# Finding standard error using only mean, min, max and Number?

Tags: statistical-significance

I want to find the standard error and standard deviation

Min. = 8 Х104
Max. = 8Х107
 -  = 9 Х106
n = 36

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are asking, could you clarify a little about your situation and your data?

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation quantifies variation among values. Without knowing all the individual values, you can't possibly calculate the standard deviation.

The standard error of the mean is computed from the standard deviation and sample size. So you can't know it either.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @HarveyMotulsky, I'll give a simple example demonstrating that the information you seek is not present in the information you have. Consider those two example vectors `a` and `b`, which are the same, except for -1 replaced with -9 (and 1 with 9):

```
a = c(-10,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,10)
print(a)
# -10  -1  -1  -1   1   1   1  10
b = c(-10,-9,-9,-9,9,9,9,10)
print(b)
# -10  -9  -9  -9   9   9   9  10
```

Those vectors have the amount of elements, min, max, and mean...

```
min(a); min(b)
# [1] -10
# [1] -10
max(a); max(b)
# [1] 10
# [1] 10
mean(a); mean(b)
# [1] 0
# [1] 0
```

...but not the same standard deviation:

```
sd(a); sd(b)
# [1] 5.424811
# [1] 9.899495
```

So, in case you only have the nr. of elements, min, max, and mean, though they tell you something about your data, you still have an infinite amount of options for which data originated those, thereby an infinite amount of possible standard deviations.